# weak reference cause crash bug

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have seen the following code in WWDC 2011-  Session 322 Objective-C Advancement in Depth

```
-(void) startBlinker{
    __weak MyClass * weakSelf = self;

    blinker = [BlinkerService register:^{
        MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if(strongSelf){
            [strongSelf->myView blink];
        }
    }];

}
```

I think I can implement it just check weakSelf like

```
if(weakSelf){
    [weakSelf->myView blink];
}
```

why the code use a strongSelf?

Comment: The reason is that weakSelf could become `nil` after you check whether it's `nil` and before you access its `myView` ivar.  By creating a strong reference to it on the stack, you're guaranteed that the object will persist until sometime after the last use of the strong reference (a time determined by ARC).

Comment: thank you , please answer this question and I will accept it. can you tell me when an App may crash because access nil object? because send a message to nil will be not crash

Comment: The code `weakSelf->myView` is not sending a message to `weakSelf`, it is using the dereference operator `->`.  `weakSelf->myView` is equivalent to `(*weakSelf).myView`; as a result, if `weakSelf` is `nil`, we will dereference `NULL` (recall that `nil` and `NULL` are both the zero address) and crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object a weak reference points to is deallocated, the weak reference evaluates to nil. Calling methods on nil is okay but accessing fields using the arrow operator is not. So you have to make sure the pointer is not nil before accessing the field via the arrow pointer.

```
if(weakSelf){ // no weak sheeps this week
    // weakSelf may get deallocated at this point. 
    // In that case the next line will crash the app.
    [weakSelf->myView blink];
}
```

The strong self guarantees that self will not be deallocated between the if and the statements in the if block.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a weak reference is done like this to avoid retain cycles in blocks.  Blocks retain self which causes a retain cycle if you try to access a strong reference to self.  So you create a weak self outside the block and access it within the block to avoid the retain cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed Mohammed is correct, however another possible solution is to declare myView as a property, rather than as an iVar and do this:

```
-(void) startBlinker{
    __weak MyClass * weakSelf = self;

    blinker = [BlinkerService register:^{
        MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf.myView blink];
    }];

}
```

This way, you don't really care if strongSelf is nil or not.